# Something wrong with Gem : Gem::Exception

Tags: macos, rubygems

There is something wrong with gem when I use it on my MacBook.

The wrong message is:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it works for me; try to follow these steps (you should have homebrew installed on your mac: http://brew.sh/ and rvm: http://rvm.io/):

```
1. rvm get stable
2. rvm reload
3. brew update
4. brew install openssl
5. brew link openssl --force
6. brew install curl-ca-bundle
7. rvm autolibs enable
8. rvm remove x.x.x (x.x.x is the Ruby version you're using- e.g. 2.1.0. If you use multiple Rubies, you will need to do this for all of them. To list your rubies, use rvm rubies)
9. rvm install x.x.x (Reinstall the Ruby you just uninstalled.)
10. gem install bundler
```